# MongoDb aggregation query using $addFields and $max in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB aggregation that works in the mongo shell but returns an error when I attempt to run it from within Java application.

The aggregation query in question is as follows:

```
db.assets.aggregate([
    { $lookup: {
        from: "vulnerabilities",
        let: { id: "$_id", jdkId: "$jdkId" },
        pipeline: [
            { $match:
                { $expr:
                    { $and: [
                        { $eq: [ "$resolved",  false ] },
                        { $or: [
                            { $eq: [ "$assetId",  "$$id" ] },
                            { $eq: [ "$assetId", "$$jdkId" ] }
                        ] }
                    ] }
                 }
            }
        ],
        as: "unresolvedVulnerabilities"
    } },
    { $addFields: {
        maxCvssBaseScore: {
            $max: {
                $max: "$unresolvedVulnerabilities.cves.cvssBaseScore"
            }
        }
    } },
    { $skip: 0 },
    { $limit: 100 }
] ).pretty()
```

When I attempt to run this query in a Java application, I get the following error:

```
{
    "operationTime": {
        "$timestamp": {
            "t": 1645001907,
            "i": 1
        }
    },
    "ok": 0.0,
    "errmsg": "Invalid $addFields :: caused by :: Unrecognized expression '$max '",
    "code": 168,
    "codeName": "InvalidPipelineOperator",
    "$clusterTime": {
        "clusterTime": {
            "$timestamp": {
                "t": 1645001907,
                "i": 1
            }
        },
        "signature": {
            "hash": {
                "$binary": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=",
                "$type": "00"
            },
            "keyId": {
                "$numberLong": "0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code for generating the `addFields` stage of the aggregation pipeline is as follows:

```
        Bson addFieldsStage = new Document().append("$addFields",
            new Document().append(PROPERTY_MAX_CVSS_BASE_SCORE,
                new Document().append("$max",
                    new Document().append("$max ", "$" + PROPERTY_UNRESOLVED_VULNERABILITIES + "." + PROPERTY_CVES + "." + PROPERTY_CVSS_BASE_SCORE)
                )
            )
        );
```

An example of the underlying data is as follows:

```
{
  "id": "eb843e46-901a-3d0e-8d6e-1315c78cf5f7",
  "name": "test-server1@test.a.b.c",
  "type": "liberty",
  "productName": "WebSphere Application Server Liberty Network Deployment",
  "version": "20.0.0.9",
  "features": [
    "el-3.0",
    "jsp-2.3",
    "servlet-3.1",
    "ssl-1.0",
    "transportSecurity-1.0",
    "usageMetering-1.0"
  ],
  "apars": [],
  "hostName": "test.a.b.c",
  "serverName": "test-server1",
  "installDirectory": "/opt/ibm/wlp/",
  "profileDirectory": "/opt/ibm/wlp/usr/",
  "operatingSystem": "Linux",
  "operatingSystemVersion": "3.10.0-1160.53.1.el7.x86_64",
  "jdkId": "579a03c6-76d0-3813-ad61-51428041987b",
  "unresolvedVulnerabilities": [
    {
      "id": "156bb40b-826d-31e8-ab61-e0d3ee8b6446",
      "name": "6520468 : IBM J9 VM@test.a.b.c",
      "description": "There are multiple vulnerabilities in the IBM® SDK, Java™ Technology Edition that is shipped with IBM WebSphere Application Server. These might affect some configurations of IBM WebSphere Application Server Traditional, IBM WebSphere Application Server Liberty and IBM WebSphere Application Server Hypervisor Edition. These products have addressed the applicable CVEs. If you run your own Java code using the IBM Java Runtime delivered with this product, you should evaluate your code to determine whether the complete list of vulnerabilities is applicable to your code. For a complete list of vulnerabilities, refer to the link for \"IBM Java SDK Security Bulletin\" located in the References section for more information. HP fixes are on a delayed schedule.",
      "assetId": "579a03c6-76d0-3813-ad61-51428041987b",
      "securityBulletinId": "7e4684ae-8252-354e-be6d-4268af2d272e",
      "resolved": false,
      "cves": [
        {
          "id": "CVE-2021-35578",
          "description": "An unspecified vulnerability in Java SE related to the JSSE component could allow an unauthenticated attacker to cause a denial of service resulting in a low availability impact using unknown attack vectors.",
          "cvssBaseScore": 5.3
        },
        {
          "id": "CVE-2021-35564",
          "description": "An unspecified vulnerability in Java SE related to the Keytool component could allow an unauthenticated attacker to cause no confidentiality impact, low integrity impact, and no availability impact.",
          "cvssBaseScore": 5.3
        }
      ],
      "remediations": [
        {
          "startVersion": "8.0.0.0",
          "endVersion": "8.0.6.36",
          "fixPack": "8.0.7.0"
        }
      ],
      "created": "2022-01-11T10:58:43Z",
      "createdBy": "server-registration-processor",
      "updated": "2022-01-11T10:58:43Z",
      "updatedBy": "server-registration-processor",
      "secondsExposed": 0
    },
    {
      "id": "0f6006e6-a8ae-3cb6-bb7e-ba3afbf93996",
      "name": "6489683 : test-server1@test.a.b.c",
      "description": "There are multiple vulnerabilities in the  Apache Commons Compress library that is used by WebSphere Application Server Liberty.  This has been addressed.",
      "assetId": "eb843e46-901a-3d0e-8d6e-1315c78cf5f7",
      "securityBulletinId": "12de7238-ff4e-3252-a05f-19d51a3f8bf0",
      "resolved": false,
      "cves": [
        {
          "id": "CVE-2021-36090",
          "description": "Apache Commons Compress is vulnerable to a denial of service, caused by an out-of-memory error when large amounts of memory are allocated. By reading a specially-crafted ZIP archive, a remote attacker could exploit this vulnerability to cause a denial of service condition against services that use Compress' zip package.",
          "cvssBaseScore": 7.5
        },
        {
          "id": "CVE-2021-35517",
          "description": "Apache Commons Compress is vulnerable to a denial of service, caused by an out of memory error when allocating large amounts of memory. By persuading a victim to open a specially-crafted TAR archive, a remote attacker could exploit this vulnerability to cause a denial of service condition against services that use Compress' tar package.",
          "cvssBaseScore": 5.5
        }
      ],
      "remediations": [
        {
          "startVersion": "20.0.0.1",
          "endVersion": "20.0.0.12",
          "operator": "OR",
          "iFixes": [
            "PH39418"
          ],
          "fixPack": "21.0.0.10"
        }
      ],
      "created": "2022-01-11T10:58:43Z",
      "createdBy": "vulnerability-manager",
      "updated": "2022-01-11T10:58:43Z",
      "updatedBy": "vulnerability-manager",
      "secondsExposed": 0
    }
  ],
  "groups": [
    "NO_GROUP"
  ],
  "created": "2022-01-11T10:58:43Z",
  "createdBy": "server-registration-processor",
  "updated": "2022-01-25T15:49:16Z",
  "updatedBy": "vulnerability-manager"
}
```

Is anyone able to tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Within the `$addFields` stage `$max` is expecting an array as its input. The issue is not related to Java programming.

Comment: @prasad_ The `unresolvedVulnerabilities.cves` property is an array. This is why the definition of the stage includes nested `$max` statements.As I mentioned in the post, the aggregation query works fine when executed within the Mongo shell on the server... it only fails when executed remotely in a Java application.

Comment: @prasad_ Modifying the Java code that builds `$addFields` stage as follows generates the same error:


`Bson addFieldsStage = new Document().append("$addFields",
    new Document().append(PROPERTY_MAX_CVSS_BASE_SCORE,
        new Document().append("$max ", Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3) )
    )
);`

Comment: Why do you need to nest an extra `$max` operator? What is the data in the `"unresolvedVulnerabilities.cves.cvssBaseScore"` ?

Comment: @prasad_ I have updated my question with an example of the JSON structure.

Comment: Its a **syntax error**. `new Document().append("$max ", "$" + PROPERTY_UNRESOLVED_VULNERABILITIES ...` - The `"$max "` has an extra _space_ within the quotes. That is causing the error.

Comment: OMG... that was it!!! Great spot. I have been chasing this all day!!!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was a fat finger error... one of the `$max` strings included an additional space at the end.

The Java code for the working stage is:

```
        Bson addFieldsStage = new Document().append("$addFields",
            new Document().append(PROPERTY_MAX_CVSS_BASE_SCORE,
                new Document().append("$max",
                    new Document().append("$max", "$" + PROPERTY_UNRESOLVED_VULNERABILITIES + "." + PROPERTY_CVES + "." + PROPERTY_CVSS_BASE_SCORE)
                )
            )
        );
```

Many thanks to prasad_ for spotting this.